# How to use Scanner to read only one line at a time with integers?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, java-io

If I have a .txt file with a list of numbers. It should return the sum for all the numbers in each line as well as the sum of every number in the file. Then print all of this in the console. Lets say the txt file is:

```
50  3   21  10  9   9   54  47  24  74
22  63  63  28  36  47  60  3   45  83
20  37  11  41  47  89  9   98  40  94
48  77  93  68  8   19  81  67  80  64
41  73  24  29  99  6   41  23  23  44
43  41  29  11  43  94  62  27  81  71
83  14  97  67  21  68  77  25  21  24
31  8   54  14  49  96  33  18  14  80
54  55  53  38  62  53  62  10  42  29
17  89  92  87  15  42  50  85  68  43
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Summer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        File text = new File("src/nums.txt");

        if (!text.exists()) {
          text.createNewFile();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(text);
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            sum = sum + input.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.printf("Sum of all numbers: %d", sum);


        int lineSum = 0;
        int lineNum = 1;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                lineSum = lineSum + input.nextInt();
            } else {
                input.next();
                lineNum++;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%nSum of line %d: %d", lineNum, lineSum);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Sum of all numbers: 4687
Sum of line 1: 0
```

Comment: At the moment (in the program) you are trying to calculate the sum for lines, the scunner is at the end of the data stream. Probably it's a better idea to calcumate line sums ans total sum at the same time, e.g. in the same loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop will never work since after the first one you are at the EOF (End-Of-File) and the scanner object will not start over from the beginning.

The best thing here is to use 2 Scanner objects, one to read a line from the file and one to read the values from that line. With this solution you can count total per line and file total at once.

```
int total = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(text);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
    int lineSum = 0;
    while (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        lineSum += lineScanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Sum of line is: " + lineSum);
    total += lineSum;
}
System.out.println("File sum is: " + total);
```

My printing is a little different than yours but that's easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

Your problem here is that you are using the same `Scanner` instance to read the file twice, which is causing the problem because it already reaches the end of the file in the first `while` call, so when you recall `input.hasNext()` it will be `false` thus you won't enter the second `while`.

**Solution:**

You need to re-initialize the `input` Scanner just before the second `while` call:

```
int lineSum = 0;
int lineNum = 1;

//Re initialize the scanner instance here
input = new Scanner(text);
while (input.hasNext()) {
    //Do the calculations
}
```

**Note:**

You need also to pay attention to the `input.nextInt()` and `input.next()` calls in your calculations to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Cant believe I didn't think about that but, the second while still takes every number and not just the line of numbers. No matter what I try I can't get it to add each line individually.

Comment: @IanHank That's why I said you need to pay attention to the `input.next()` calls, it reads all the line but as a `String`, then you can get all the numbers.